# Player with 3 cards in Texas Hold'em. Now what?

Tags: texas-hold-em, nlhe, rules, dealing

We had a situation pre-flop where the UTG+3, when at his position to act, as he went to look to his cards, there were 3 cards total.

At this point, the UTG had already raised, and the UTG+1 went all in.

In this particular occasion, the party decided the UTG+3 should be disqualified from the current round in progress. As far as I know this kind of penalty is impossible.

Ironically, UTG+3 was the only seasoned player in the table and the only one with the habit of only looking at his cards when he should act. The other newbies like me look one card at a time as soon as the dealer deals it.

The extra card was like glued to another, just at looking was impossible to distinguish.

Is there a common solution to this or this is more inclined to the house rules?

Comment: I believe this is house rules, and the rule should be that the entire hand is considered misdealt. You cannot penalize one person like that.

Comment: @user2094178, you marked a wrong answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hand should proceed, and UTG+3's hand should be declared dead.

The answers that say this is a misdeal are flat out wrong. So much action has already happened in the hand that it makes absolutely no sense to declare a misdeal unless you're using some very particular (and bad) house rules that everyone has had access to.

In particular, in [Robert's Rules of Poker](http://www.pokercoach.us/RobsPkrRules4.htm), Section #3."Misdeals".#2 states:
"[...] action is considered to occur when two players after the blinds have acted on their hands. Once action occurs, a misdeal can no longer be declared. The hand will be played to conclusion and no money will be returned to any player whose hand is fouled."

Section #3."Dead Hands".#1 states

"Your hand is declared dead if:
[...]
(d) The hand does not contain the proper number of cards for that particular game"

So, as we see, UTG+3's hand should be declared dead, and play should proceed.

Answer (score 2):

This is a miss deal.  You can't just penalize the player who got dealt an extra card and continue play as if all is well.

Once it has been declared a miss deal all players muck their cards (a few players usually complain because they have an ace/pair in their hand). Then the hand is re-dealt in the same position as if the miss deal didn't happen

Comment: I stand corrected, Mobius dumpling is has given the right answer.    These are the official TDA rules taken from http://www.pokertda.com/custom_posts/view-official-tda-rules/                                               "If substantial action occurs, a misdeal cannot be declared and the hand must proceed.

35:   Substantial Action.

Substantial Action is either: A) any two actions in turn, at least one of which puts chips in the pot (i.e. any 2 actions except 2 checks or 2 folds); OR B) any combination of three actions in turn (check, bet, raise, call, or fold). See also Rules 34 and 38."